# Is it normal for so many ruby processes to be running?

Tags: ruby, linux, process

I'm having issues with a site on my server loading and was running 'top' and saw this:

[alt text http://share.shpigford.com/images/ruby_processes-20091112-103834.png](http://share.shpigford.com/images/ruby_processes-20091112-103834.png)

Dozens of ruby processes...and I have no idea what that means or if that's normal. :)

Comment: Are you using ruby for anything?  Perhaps CGI with Apache?  They are eating quite a bit of system resources.

Comment: Well it's a Rails app running on Apache w/ Passenger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that your [PassengerMaxPoolSize](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options) is set too high for such a small amount of memory.  Just totaling that up your ruby processes are eating 81% of your available memory.

See this related discussion on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/15350/running-ruby-on-rails-app-on-apache-passenger-to-much-memory).  This question should probably be migrated over there.

Comment: I hadn't set PassengerMaxPoolSize at all...the discussion at ServerFault helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is normal on your system.

In a sever production environment ruby scales by adding processes, so I would expect to see at least one process per CPU core. (Real or virtual - my i7 920 has 8 virtual cores and needs 8 ruby processes for a 100% CPU load.)

Dozens sound like a lot, but it could be possible if your site is using lots of ruby for miscellaneous daemon processes.

I think you'll have to ask someone who knows what is supposed to run on the system.

Comment: That's me. :) I have a 512MB slice with Slicehost.

Comment: Know the feeling :) There are way too many processes for 512 MB. Did you try out the links from Mark?